# Count of all and count some values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table,

```
uid  order_price
1    10
1    34
1    21
2    16
2    35
2    45
```

i want the count of uid in the table and the count of uid where order price >= 30, like so..

```
uid  all  above30
1    3    1
2    3    2
```

i did this :

```
select 
  uid,
  count(1),
  count(case when order_price >= 30 then 1 else 0 )
from table 
group by uid;
```

but i get this result :

```
uid all above30
1   3   3
2   3   3
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

This expression:

```
count(case when order_price >= 30 then 1 else 0 end)
```

counts all rows because all branches of `case` return a non `null` value.
Remove the `else` part:

```
count(case when order_price >= 30 then 1 end)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a108f6fae879bf9855fb5d248849e43).
Results:

```
> uid | all | above30
> --: | --: | ------:
>   1 |   3 |       1
>   2 |   3 |       2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select 
  uid,
  count(1),
  sum(case when order_price >= 30 then 1 else 0 end)
from table 
group by uid;
```

Demo:

```
# select * from t;
 uid | order_price 
-----+-------------
   1 |          10
   1 |          34
   1 |          21
   2 |          16
   2 |          35
   2 |          45
(6 rows)

# select uid, count(1), sum(case when order_price >=30 then 1 else 0 end) from t group by uid order by uid;
 uid | count | sum 
-----+-------+-----
   1 |     3 |   1
   2 |     3 |   2
(2 rows)
```